# MySQL USE in .SQL Dumps

Tags: mysql, sql, database, linux

When I backup my MySQL database using this command:

```
mysqldump -u username -pPASSWORD database_name | gzip > db_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

this gets added to the beginning of every dump:

```
USE `database_name`;
```

I did some research, and it appears the  `--databases` option can be a cause of this, but as you can see from my statement, I am not using this.

Thank you in advance from a Linux Newb :)!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a dump of the database is made, the

```
USE 'database_name';
```

is automatically added at the front, making it viable for you to set up the database again elsewhere without requiring you to rename it every single time that you wish to re-use it.

It shouldn't matter what OS you're using (I get this in Windows as-well by default).

Comment: Thank you - is it possible to not get that added to the front?

Comment: Don't think so but you can remove it ya self if you want, manually.